# phpunit throws Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I have a Zend Framework project, and want to using unit testing to test it.

In tests folder, I have the `phpunit.xml` as following;

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    <directory>./</directory>
</testsuite>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
            <file>../application/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>

<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/reprot" charset="UTP-8"
    yui="true" highlight = "true" lowUpoerBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
    <log type="textdox" target="./log/testdox.html" />
</logging>
```

And I have `bootstrap.php` in /tests/application folder as follows:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

require_once 'controllers/ControllerTestCase.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

when I go to the command line, run the following command

```
phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```

it throws the exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message
'Neither "Application Test Suite.php" nor "Application Test Suite.php" could be
opened.' in D:\PHP\php5\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 D:\PHP\php5\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(157): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test-
>__construct('Application Tes...', '')
#1 D:\PHP\php5\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run
(Array, true)
#2 D:\PHP\php5\phpunit(53): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\PHP\php5\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php on line 102
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Youll notice its throwing the exception because its looking for a file named the same as the `name` you provided for your test suite. You need to actually write a test suite and then supply the name of that test suite to your config: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/organizing-test-suites.html

Comment: I add the following code under the folder which contains bootstrap.php<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
 
// ...
 
class MyApp extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('MyApp');
 
        $suite->addTestSuite('MyApp');
        // ...
 
        return $suite;
    }
} and it is still the same error

Comment: Did you change the name you providede in you XML? This needs to correspond directly to the filename of the test suite class minus the extension. So if the code you just posted is in `MyApp.php` then your xml should look like: `<testsuite name="MyApp">` as opposed to `<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">`

Comment: yes, I already changed the name in xml file,the error is the same

Comment: @ratzip: Its doubtful you have the exact same error. Pleas post the new error message unles it is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Now, the error gone, but it gives another error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789733/need-help-for-the-zend-unit-test, I am new to zend and phpunit, it really drive me nuts, can you help me on this.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem with the same setup. From what I understand, more recent versions of PHPUnit require at least one actual test to run properly. After creating a simple test, it worked.

*myProject/tests/application/DemoTest.php*

```
<?php
class DemoTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testCanDoUnitTest() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're not using the `<testsuites>` which contains multiple occurences of `<testsuite>`.

Here is my phpunit.xml which works fine for Zend Framework projects:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="UnitTests">
    <directory>./library</directory>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="ApplicationTests">
    <directory>./application</directory>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```